# Converting live images from ROS to Gstreamer video

Tags: c++, video-streaming, gstreamer, ros

Currently I have a topic where a camera publishes sensor_msgs/Image messages and I have two Gstreamer cpp files (a Server and Client) that take the video from /dev/video0 and network it to the Client.

I would like to use the images from that topic, give them in input to the Server and stream them to the Client. How can I do that?

Server code, translated in command line:

```
gst-launch-1.0 v4l2src device = /dev/video0 ! 'video/x-raw, format=(string)YUY2, width=640, height=480, pass=qual, quantizer=20, framerate=30/1' ! videoconvert ! x264enc bitrate = 500 threads = 2 speed-preset = ultrafast byte-stream = true ! rtph264pay ! udpsink host = 127.0.0.1 port=1234
```

Client code, translated in command line:

```
gst-launch-1.0 udpsrc port=1234 ! "application/x-rtp, media=(string)video, clock-rate=(int)90000, encoding-name=(string)H264, payload=255" ! rtph264depay ! queue ! avdec_h264 ! videoconvert! videoscale! xvimagesink sync=false
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should consider using appsrc element in order to get data from another application into a GStreamer pipeline.

You can get more informations about this element in the GStreamer documentation: https://gstreamer.freedesktop.org/data/doc/gstreamer/head/gst-plugins-base-libs/html/gst-plugins-base-libs-appsrc.html